# Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path for gnu gcc compiler in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks

I have installed Code::Blocks in Ubuntu for the first time and tried to run a simple C program. But I got the error:
`Can't find compiler executable in your search path (GNU GCC Compiler)`. I tried many ways to solve this. But alas!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Linux Mint 21, I installed Code::Blocks with mint software manager, that Code::Blocks has problems and with the deb package is imposible the installation. But I solved the problem with full Code::Blocks uninstall and purge and after I install Code::Blocks with this guide:

[How to Install Code::Blocks in Ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/install-code-blocks-ubuntu/)

```
sudo apt install g++
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install codeblocks -y
```

And reboot

Answer (score 0):

Open Code::Blocks, go to *Settings* and then go to *Compiler*. Global compiler settings will open, there go to *Toolchain executables* and set the path as `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW` and then click okay.

This worked for me. Although I don't use it in Ubuntu, it may work for you. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my computer by hitting "Reset Defaults", the far right button on the compilers dialog box, which you can load by hitting the menu item Settings->Compilers.

I believe it was caused by installing CodeBlocks first without mingw, then later installing the version with it.